# Split single hash type to multiple documents by Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I plan to build my own Elasticsearch monitoring cluster. by query metrics and stats from Elasticsearch source and write to Elasticsearch monitoring cluster.

But when I query with "GET /_nodes/stats", I get the hash result like this.

```
{"nodes":{ 
  "W4x_8xNSSquKqR8YxUZLrw": { 
      "timestamp": 1486692663526,
      "name": "myserver1",
      ...
  }, 
  "W4x_8xNSSquKqR8YxUZLra" :{
      "timestamp": 1486693663526,
      "name": "myserver2",
      ...
  },
  "W4x_8xNSSquKqR8YxUZaaa" :{
      "timestamp": 1486693633326,
      "name": "myserver3",
      ...
  }
}}
```

How to use Logstash to split the result from this document to 3 documents? and then, move the nodeId to be a field value like.

```
{
      "nodeId": "W4x_8xNSSquKqR8YxUZLrw",
      "timestamp": 1486692663526,
      "name": "myserver1",
      ...
}
{
      "nodeId": "W4x_8xNSSquKqR8YxUZLra",
      "timestamp": 1486693663526,
      "name": "myserver2",
      ...
}
{
      "nodeId": "W4x_8xNSSquKqR8YxUZaaa",
      "timestamp": 1486693633326,
      "name": "myserver3",
      ...
}
```

Comment: Thats json, not a hash, how are you inputting this into logstash? and are you using the json codec?

Comment: I used "json" filter plugin to transform the input, ex. filter { json { source => message} }. But, when I tried to use "split" filter plugin, I got an error message that the split cannot accept "hash" value.